# Radio button keyboard trap

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I'm creating a multiple choice question exercise and am having issues with keyboard accessibility. Basically, the user is not able to cycle through the list of radio buttons through the keyboard. When the "focus" cursor is over a radio button and the user pressed the arrow key to move onto the next radio button a keyboard trap occurs. Instead of simply focusing it, the radio button is selected instead and thus the answer is displayed. How can I stop radio buttons being selected when going through them with the keyboard?

**HTML** markup:

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
<p class="instructions">Click on the correct answer.</p>

<ol start="49">
    <!-- Start of multiple choice question -->
    <li class="multipleChoice gradedQuestion">
        <p class="question">If you receive a request for an extension from a trader, you should:</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="questionNumber" value="49">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="answerOption"><label for="question49A">Refer to IP 13; if the original requirements are still being met, approve the extension.</label></div>
                <div class="inputAndIdContainer"><input type="radio" name="question49" value="0" id="question49A"> A.</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="answerOption"><label for="question49B">Refer to IP 20; if the original requirements are still being met, approve the extension.</label></div>


        <div class="inputAndIdContainer"><input type="radio" name="question49" value="0" id="question49B"> B.</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="answerOption"><label for="question49C">Refer to FW1; if the original requirements are still being met, approve the extension.</label></div>
            <div class="inputAndIdContainer"><input type="radio" name="question49" value="1" id="question49C"> C.</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="feedback">
        <div class="answeredCorrectly">Correct</div>
        <div class="answeredIncorrectly">Incorrect</div>
        <div class="answer">
            <strong>Answer:</strong> C - Refer to FW1.
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<!-- End of multiple choice question -->
```

Comment: Share the code with us so we can help troubleshoot?

Comment: I added the HTML code, basically cycling across the radio buttons with the keyboard makes the next one select. How do I stop that?

Comment: Tabs are used to move from field to field, not arrow keys.

Comment: I seem to be unable to select the next input in the list by using tab. After focusing the first radio button in the list, if I press tab again it simply shifts the focus to the top of the page again.

Comment: @user1410668, what j08691 said is misleading. When you group radios and checkboxes, even though you may have 5 in a group, it only gets one tab-stop. This is so people don't have to hit tab a ton of times

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer is you can't, and this isn't a keyboard trap. That is the nature of a radio.

If they are grouped together (name attribute), you tab into it; by pressing space you select the first item, by using the arrow keys it selects the next item. You should write your JS to watch for focus to enter the group and then leave. Once left, show `<div id="feedback">` or make a button to show it.

**Edit** Regarding your other post, you probably need to add a .focus() function that is similar to .click().

Answer (score 3):

That's the way they should work, take a look at [this](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/kbd.html) document!

Basically  it's this:

*On IE, when a radio button group is reached via tabbing, the initially selected button is focused on, and the dotted rectangle indicates this. You can use arrow keys to move between the buttons inside the group; both "down" and "right" arrow move forward inside the group, and both "up" and "left" arrow move backward. And upon moving to a button, that button gets checked (and the button in the group that was checked gets unchecked).*

*On Netscape, things are different. When a set of radio buttons is reached via tabbing, the first button receives focus. You can move forward inside the group by tabbing. Moving to a button that way does not change the setting. Use the space bar or Enter key to check a button.*

Comment: I am able to move inside the group of radio buttons, but as you stated the issue is they are being checked without pressing space. There is no way to prevent them from being checked until space bar or enter key is hit? No javascript code or HTML tag?

Comment: You can make an event with `JS` `onkeypress() or even use `JQuery`, but is that really necessary? I mean, it's gonna complicate things up, just `tab` to get into one `radio button`, then move to pick the one you want, then `tab` again to move to the next controller of your page

Comment: @user1410668 you may be able to, I strongly recomend against it. Doing this may confuse people.

Comment: I know, the issue is that when I tab to get to one radio button then try to move to the next one it selects the next one instead of focusing it. I'm trying to make it so it simply focus instead of activating the .click function.

Comment: You would have to undo what all, or most, browsers do on purpose. Undoing that would confuse people and/or take a step backward in accessibilty. You should do what I suggested in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by blurring the input after it's been clicked.

At least with this way if you are navigating using tab/space/arrow keys it will not mess with the user. If they click it's very unlikely they will be using arrow keys to select the next option.

Jquery:

```
$('.quiz input:radio').click(function(){ $(this).blur()})
```

Comment: This has done the trick i.e. stopping the arrow key navigation. But it disabled it even if you come to radio button through tab. It takes one arrow key and then looses focus...Any clue?