# Bootstrap: Access radio buttons using tab press

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

I have a Bootstrap form. When using the keyboard tab button, starting from the first field, I can navigate through  the form fields. However, I have a radio buttons entry (Administrator/Operator) that is skipped by tab presses.

How can I have the form's radio buttons accessible via tab presses?

```
<form class='form-horizontal'>
  <div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label'>Username</label>
    <div class='controls'>
      <input type='text' class='username' id='new-user-username' placeholder='Username'
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label'>Rights</label>
    <div class='controls'>
      <div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons-radio' id='new-user-rights'> <span class='btn'>Administrator</span>
 <span class='btn' id='new-user-operator'>Operator</span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label'>Password</label>
    <div class='controls'>
      <input type='password' class='password' id='new-user-password' placeholder='Password'
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label'>Confirm password</label>
    <div class='controls'>
      <input type='password' class='confirm' id='new-user-confirm' placeholder='Confirm password'
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='controls'>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='new-user-button'>Add new user</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This was asked before, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739863/radio-button-keyboard-trap/10740595#10740595. You aree trying to do something that you don't need to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not achieve too much, because if you were to tab through the inputs, you would just simply tab trough the radios, and you cannot do anything with it, because if you wanted to press enter to select one, the form would be sent.

Regardless, you could use the HTML [`tabindex`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) attribute:

```
<input type='password' tabindex="1">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/MgcDU/1304/)

**Edit based on your comment:**

Include the following code:

```
$('#new-user-rights span').keyup(function(e){
    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == 32){
        $('#new-user-rights span').removeClass('active')
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/MgcDU/1306/)

Comment: Ok, so you've partly solved the problem. Maybe a bit of JavaScript to replace `space` by `click` when a radio button is selected would do the job.

Comment: @Randomblue Replace what exactly?

Comment: Listen to `keypress` event and if the keycode is `space` then generate a `click` on the selected radio.

Comment: @Randomblue I can and will try, but there's no guarantee for the fact that I'll be able to provide a vanilla solution for that. If jQuery is OK, I can edit the answer now.

Comment: Yes, jQuery will work just fine, and it should only be a couple lines.

Comment: I wish Bootstrap gave this a thorough think-through.